# SwipeTab returns Action Bar must have a callback exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, tabs

Hi I'm having an error on my Swipe Tab Activity of

> Action Bar must have callback

I believe I followed the correct implementation of it but still get this error.

> 02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thesis.docdroid/com.thesis.docdroid.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Action Bar Tab must have a Callback
>   02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
>   02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2099)
>   02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
>   02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
>   02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4929)
>   02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
>   02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
>   02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Action Bar Tab must have a Callback
>   02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.configureTab(ActionBarImpl.java:549)
>   02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:575)
>   02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:563)
>   02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812):     at com.thesis.docdroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
>   02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5254)
>   02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
>   02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2038)
>   02-28 22:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5812):     ... 11 more

This is my code:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener {
    private String selectedProfileName;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        Bundle args = getIntent().getExtras();
        selectedProfileName = args.getString("key_name");

        InitializeActionBar();

    }

    public void InitializeActionBar() {
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab tabBodyPart = actionBar.newTab();
        tabBodyPart.setText("Body Parts");
        tabBodyPart.setTabListener(MainActivity.this);

        ActionBar.Tab tabGeneralSymptoms = actionBar.newTab();
        tabBodyPart.setText("General Symptoms");
        tabBodyPart.setTabListener(MainActivity.this);

        ActionBar.Tab tabSelectedSymptoms = actionBar.newTab();
        tabBodyPart.setText("Selected Symptoms");
        tabBodyPart.setTabListener(MainActivity.this);

        actionBar.addTab(tabBodyPart);
        actionBar.addTab(tabGeneralSymptoms);
        actionBar.addTab(tabSelectedSymptoms);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy Pasta error.

You have:

```
tabBodyPart.setText("General Symptoms");
tabBodyPart.setTabListener(MainActivity.this);
```

You want :

```
tabGeneralSymptoms.setText("General Symptoms");
tabGeneralSymptoms.setTabListener(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Oh you're right! That made me look stupid. hahaha, thanks for noticing. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the action bar, which is not supported in v4 library, use v7 instead. Use `ActionBarActivty`, which extends `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: My problem was already solved on the comment above by @meredrica. Thanks for answering though.